# Parse nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON on a URL:

```
{
   "href":"http:\/\/api.rwlabs.org\/v1\/jobs?limit=10",
   "time":18,
   "links":
   {
      "self":
      {
         "href":"http:\/\/api.rwlabs.org\/v1\/jobs?offset=0&limit=10&preset=minimal"
      },
      "next":
      {
          "href":"http:\/\/api.rwlabs.org\/v1\/jobs?offset=10&limit=10&preset=minimal"
      }
   },
   "totalCount":2279,
   "count":10,
   "data":[
      {
       "id":"1148141",
       "score":1,
       "href":"http:\/\/api.rwlabs.org\/v1\/jobs\/1148141",
       "fields":
         { 
           "title":"Volunteer Renewable Energy Programmes Coordinator"
         }
       },
       {
        "id":"1147901",
        "score":1,
        "href":"http:\/\/api.rwlabs.org\/v1\/jobs\/1147901",
        "fields":
          {
            "title":"Volunteer Project Management Coordinators \/ Intern"
          }
       }
  /* so on*/
```

And I want get the information inside "data" and inside "fields".
If I remove the part before data array, I can get some of the values, but fields returns undefined. Although I also need to have a solution without removing the information before data.

JS

```
var table = '<table><thead><th>id</th><th>title</th></thead><tbody>';
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(obj, function(i, val) {
    table += '<tr><td>' + this['id'] + '</td><td>' + this['obj[i].title'] + '</td></tr>';
});
table += '</tbody></table>';
document.getElementById("datalist").innerHTML = table;
```

(I also do not know how to parse the data from the URL, so for now I am copying the data into the script)

[JSFiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/1v803c3L/1/ Although I have part of the data on the code, even though the entire information is on an URL as seen on the code I posted.

Comment: can you make a fiddle for better understanding ?

Comment: `$.each(obj.data, function (i, val) { ... val.id ... val.fields.title ... })`

Comment: Editted with the Fiddle

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/1v803c3L/3/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`obj.data[i].fields.title` where `i` is an int that you use to index into the data array